# Есть ли вариант более "изящной" реализации?

Tags: javascript, jquery

- Есть большая таблица `5 cols` и примерно `100 rows`
- В каждой строчке есть ссылка `edit`
- Нужно вытащить данные для редактирования в `<input type="text />`

Сделал по "индусски" но в принципе работает:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var k = $(this).data('row');
    $('input[name="a"]').val(document.getElementById('items').rows[k].cells[0].innerHTML);  
    $('input[name="b"]').val(document.getElementById('items').rows[k].cells[1].innerHTML);   
    $('input[name="c"]').val(document.getElementById('items').rows[k].cells[2].innerHTML);   
    $('input[name="d"]').val(document.getElementById('items').rows[k].cells[3].innerHTML);  
    $('input[name="e"]').val(document.getElementById('items').rows[k].cells[4].innerHTML);
});
```

Может есть более "галантные" варианты? Что то вроде `js\jquery` нативного `serialize();` ? Или моя реализация всё таки "приемлема"?

Вот фиддл поиграться: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/TtU9M/

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TtU9M/4/

Если количество инпутов и ячеек в строке совпадает то так:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr').first(),
        cells = tr.children('td'),
        inputs = $('#inputs').children('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs.eq(i).val(cells.eq(i).html());
    }
    // а номер строки можно получить:
    var row = $('#items').children('tr').index(tr);
});
```

объясните зачем вам jquery если вы пишите `document.getElementById('items')` ?

Comment: У меня не работало $('#tableid').rows[k].cells[4].text(); ноя совсем забыл про Childer('tr')! Спасибо огромное Вам!